# Continuation of figure in tabular format in multiple pages

Tags: tables, floats, formatting

I am facing problem writing my thesis in Latex. The trouble is I have a bunch of figure that I want to present in tabular format (shown in the picture below) but the figure is larger and do not fit in a page as well as it is not continued in next page instead some part of the figure goes missing. Please have a look the code I wrote and It will be really helpful if someone can help me figure out this problem:

```
\documentclass[ final, oneside,12pt,letterpaper]{report}
\usepackage[letterpaper,left=1.5in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{c c}
            \includegraphics[width=.40\textwidth]{1.eps} & 
            \includegraphics[width=.40\textwidth]{2.eps} \\

            \includegraphics[width=.40\textwidth]{3.eps} & 
            \includegraphics[width=.40\textwidth]{4.eps} \\ 

            \includegraphics[width=.40\textwidth]{5.eps} & 
            \includegraphics[width=.40\textwidth]{6.eps} \\

            \includegraphics[width=.40\textwidth]{7.eps} & 
            \includegraphics[width=.40\textwidth]{8.eps} \\

            \includegraphics[width=.40\textwidth]{9.eps} &
            \includegraphics[width=.40\textwidth]{10.eps} \\

        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Trying to fit this image in }
        \label{fig: HF vs epsilon}
    \end{figure}
 \end{document}
```

Figure should be some thing like shown below. The image in the picture is scaled down so that it fits in a page but for my problem it is larger and do not fit in one page and do not continue to the next page.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please clarify what you're trying to achieve. Do you want to shrink the sizes of the graphs so that they all fit on a single page, or do you want to have LaTeX insert a page break, if needed, and continue on the following page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For arrangement images as multi-page figure, you have more possibilities:

- not use float environment and put images into `longtable`
- use floats and divide images between them and for caption use `\ContinuedFloat` option from package `caption`.

The first case:

```
\documentclass[final, oneside,12pt,letterpaper]{report}
\usepackage[letterpaper,left=1.5in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
{
        \centering
\begin{longtable}{c c}
    \includegraphics[width=.40\textwidth]{example-image} &
    \includegraphics[width=.40\textwidth]{example-image} \\

    \includegraphics[width=.40\textwidth]{example-image} &
    \includegraphics[width=.40\textwidth]{example-image} \\

    \includegraphics[width=.40\textwidth]{example-image} &
    \includegraphics[width=.40\textwidth]{example-image} \\

    \includegraphics[width=.40\textwidth]{example-image} &
    \includegraphics[width=.40\textwidth]{example-image} \\

    \includegraphics[width=.40\textwidth]{example-image} &
    \includegraphics[width=.40\textwidth]{example-image} \\

    \includegraphics[width=.40\textwidth]{example-image} &
    \includegraphics[width=.40\textwidth]{example-image} \\

    \includegraphics[width=.40\textwidth]{example-image} &
    \includegraphics[width=.40\textwidth]{example-image} \\
\end{longtable}
\captionof{figure}{Trying to fit this image in }
    \label{fig: HF vs epsilon}
}
 \end{document}
```

The second case:

```
\documentclass[final, oneside,12pt,letterpaper]{report}
\usepackage[letterpaper,left=1.5in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
\begin{tabular}{c c}
    \includegraphics[width=.40\textwidth]{example-image} &
    \includegraphics[width=.40\textwidth]{example-image} \\

    \includegraphics[width=.40\textwidth]{example-image} &
    \includegraphics[width=.40\textwidth]{example-image} \\

    \includegraphics[width=.40\textwidth]{example-image} &
    \includegraphics[width=.40\textwidth]{example-image} \\

    \includegraphics[width=.40\textwidth]{example-image} &
    \includegraphics[width=.40\textwidth]{example-image} \\
\end{tabular}
\caption{figure}{Trying to fit this image in (continued on the next page}
    \label{fig: HF vs epsilon}
    \end{figure}
    
    \begin{figure}
\ContinuedFloat
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{c c}
    \includegraphics[width=.40\textwidth]{example-image} &
    \includegraphics[width=.40\textwidth]{example-image} \\

    \includegraphics[width=.40\textwidth]{example-image} &
    \includegraphics[width=.40\textwidth]{example-image} \\

    \includegraphics[width=.40\textwidth]{example-image} &
    \includegraphics[width=.40\textwidth]{example-image} \\
\end{tabular}
\caption{figure}{Trying to fit this image in (continued from previous page)}
    \label{fig: HF vs epsilon}
     \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much for your help.